# How to connect the "disable pin" of IC if I don't want to use that pin's feature?

Tags: integrated-circuit, grounding, decoupling-capacitor

In one project I am planning to use an IR2104 half bridge driver.  It features a pin called "SD" on the datasheet whose purpose is to disable the IC if a positive voltage is applied to it.

I am not planning to use this feature.

What should I do with this pin?

Not connect it anywhere, connect it directly to ground, connect it to ground through a capacitor (and if through an electrolytic capacitor, which polarity goes to ground in this case,) etc.?

Edit: My intuition would be to connect that SD pin to ground through an electrolytic capacitor with the + side of the capacitor connected to ground and its - side connected to the IC. The reasoning is that if the ground line becomes transiently positive (because it is not an ideal conductor and has a non-zero resistance,) charges will accumulate in the capacitor and thus be drawn away from the IC. Is that wrong?

Comment: Note that it's a \$\overline{SD}\$ pin, not an \$SD\$ pin, signifying negation; in other words, assert that pin to not shutdown. I miss the days when such pins were just marked EN for enable.

Comment: I see, yes, seems obvious in retrospect, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The term "assert" usually means to put the pin/input into its active, or asserted state.  So for an input that's active high, that would mean applying a high signal to the pin.  For an input that's active low, that means pulling the input to a logic low or ground (for positive voltage powered devices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal block diagram for IR2104 in [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7c1c31671) makes it clear that the SD pin is **internally pulled to ground** through a resistor. If you leave it unconnected or connect it to ground, the IC will remain in shutdown mode.

[image: block diagram]

The timing diagram also makes it clear that the IC will remain in shutdown mode if SD is at a logic **low** level. Hence, I would recommend connecting it to **VCC** so that the IC remains out of shutdown mode.

[image: timing diagram]

Comment: Oh, I guess I had this totally wrong then, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome.